# How to stop infinite cola layout manually?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I had used infinite option in cola layout to draw the nodes and their connections. I was trying to add manual stop function to this when all the nodes in the graph get well settled. But I couldn't find a way to do this.
So, how can I manually stop the cola layout?
I cannot use max simulation time option as the number of nodes in the graph and their connections can vary and so deciding this time is not possible.

As a hack, I am using currently like

```
var simulationStopTimer = setInterval(function (){  
     if (simulationStopNow){  
       options.infinite = false;
       adaptor.stop();  
       clearInterval(simulationStopTimer);             
     }          
  }, 10000);
```

So, i am using a timer every 10 seconds to check whether the user has clicked a button to stop the layout. Is there is any better way?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a layout object, you can call `layout.stop()` : http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/layout-manipulation/layout.stop

For your case, however, that is unnecessary:

Physics layouts automatically stop once they're settled.  Make sure to set your force parameters appropriately.   And turn the time limit to a high value so the layout doesn't stop prematurely.